# Minimum table column width when resizing the column

Tags: gui-design, tables

In the table that I’m working on, user are able to resize any columns within the table. However, we would like to prevent user from resizing the column to a point where it’s like collapsing the column.

Is there a best practice for setting the minimum width of a table column when resizing the column itself? Ideally I would want to set a width which can be applied across all the tables within the system.

Appreciate if anyone could share any details or articles that I can look into. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whats in the data table? phrase, sentences, loading bars, integers, user defined names, etc.?

Each of those require a different amount of minimal space to discern. I'm assuming it's names or phrases. If this is the case, then the column width should not collapse further than the width of the column header, or even the expected string length.

In most cases, you will come across data in a table that requires disclosure, like a long name or a description. In this situation it's more important to design around how the user can read the full value if the string when the data is truncated (EG: tool-tips).